# Как добавить на default.aspx контрол С# windowsform webbrowser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, windows, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет) Я еще не очень разбираюсь в   ASP. Всего лишь поднял простенький сайт на фри хостинге. Но появилась интересная задумка: хочу в веб приложении на ASP .net MVC 3 создать 
встроенный web browser, который в два клика добавляется на  windowsForm  в обычном C#. Ну, с целью,  скажем просмотра веб страниц прямо с сервера хостера) ПОнимаю конечно что это не самая хорошая идея, и,  думаю,   многие скажут что это бред полнейший и невозможно(я уже гуглил)но наверное же есть какой то способ сделать хотя бы подобие? 
Вобщем вопрос состоит в том,  как добавить на default.aspx (ASP .net MVC 3 движок ASPX) контрол С# windowsform webbrowser. Заранее спасибо за содержательные ответы.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам браузер в мвц проекте? о_О Клиентом такого приложения итак является браузер - зачем вам браузер внутри браузера? Если же вам нужно в вебном приложении иметь возможность просмотра других сайтов или страниц в рамках своего приложения используйте просто фреймы.

Comment: Задумка в следующем: на сервере я захостил ASP .net MVC, и нужно чтобы на странице был встроенный, работающий браузер, именно "браузер внутри браузера" - полноценный, работающий с сookies, с IP адресом хостера. Фреймы этих возможностей не дадут, к сожалению : \ 
Прежде всего  - это делается в целях обучения, вот и загорелся этой идеей. Хочу найти решение, так как сам еще не силен решил обратиться к знающим людям,  спасибо за ответ)

Comment: может есть еще возможные варианты решения задачи? Вот уже начинаю подумывать в сторону создания метода,  работающего с http запросами, это, думаю,  в консольном режиме все можно реализовать. Но куда потом передать для правильного отображения эти http ответы с серверов? (в рамках сервера, а не браузера клиента) :\

Comment: Никогда не видел подобного или не правильно вас понимаю - можете привести пример любого аналога вашей задачи?

Comment: Я одного не могу понять (предположим вы решили как то вашу задачу и у вас есть браузер внутри браузера): зачем пользователям вашего саита может понадобиться из внутреннего браузера открывать какие то другие сайты? Почему бы просто не открыть новую вкладку в стандартном браузере (ИЕ, ФФ, неважно) и не подгрузить етот еще один или несколько саитов? Задача, как вы сказали, исключительно учебная, но если она не применима в жизни (а пока что мне кажется именно так), то и учиться на ней смысла особо нет.

Comment: :) я понимаю,  что это звучит смешно, или может я недостаточно понятно всё описал.....Как бы это выразить точнее, ну например существуют онлайн сервисы  типа "виртуальный онлайн-компьютер", "интернет-ОС",  "браузерная ОС" 

Источник: http://netler.ru/pc/icloud.htm (там подробно написано)

вот и я хочу реализовать как бы "виртуальный браузер" :)

Comment: ну как же не применима,например, им можно будет пользоваться как "аналогом прокси серверов", IP адрес то другой будет, тот же банальный случай : когда у многих на работе закрыт доступ "вкантагтЭ" - а тут вуаля - виртуальный браузер и всё работает)) и не нужно никаких сомнительных прокси,  админских прав на машине клиента, и хостинг,  как я уже говорил я юзаю бесплатный,  да и мало ли для чего еще можно его будет использовать)

Answer (score 0):

ЗЫ: " именно "браузер внутри браузера" - полноценный, работающий с сookies, и под IP адресом хостера ", работающий как процесс на сервере,  но который выводил бы отображение веб страниц в на ЭТОМ же сайте,  в какой-нибудь отдельной,  созданной специально для этого форме... :)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону Citrix.